# C++ errors with releasing Dynamic memory

Tags: c++

Error - *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff360: pointer being freed was not allocated.

*I understand its better to use vectors, but our prof wants us to use it this way.*

My unwrap function is giving me errors where I want to release the memory, also when I want to print the pattern using the for loop in the *display* function it gives me a garbage value out of memory instead of printing out the pattern itself. I tested using cout in the wrap function and it works there but not in my display function.

```
bool wrap(Gift& theGift){

    if (theGift.m_wrap == nullptr) {
        cout << "Wrapping gifts..." << endl;

        do {
            cout << "Enter the number of wrapping layers for the Gift: ";
            cin >> theGift.m_wrapLayers;
        }while ((theGift.m_wrapLayers <= 0) && cout << "Layers at minimum must be 1, try again." << endl);

        theGift.m_wrap = new Wrapping[theGift.m_wrapLayers];
        char buffer[100];
        int patternLength;

        for (int i = 0; i < theGift.m_wrapLayers; i++) {
            cout << "Enter wrapping pattern #" << i + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> buffer;
            patternLength = (unsigned)strlen(buffer);
            theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = new char[patternLength + 1];
            theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = buffer;
            cout << theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern << endl;
        }
        return true;

    }else {
        cout << "Gift is already wrapped!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

bool unwrap(Gift& theGift){
    if (theGift.m_wrap != nullptr) {
        cout << "Gift being unwrapped." << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < theGift.m_wrapLayers; i++) {
            delete[] theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern;
            theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = nullptr;
        }
        delete[] theGift.m_wrap;
        theGift.m_wrap = nullptr;

        return true;
    }else{
        cout << "Gift isn't wrapped! Cannot unwrap." << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

void display(Gift& theGift){
        cout << "Gift Details: " << endl;
        cout << " Description: " << theGift.m_description << endl;
        cout << "       Price: " << theGift.m_price << endl;
        cout << "       Units: " << theGift.m_units << endl;
        cout << "Wrap Layers: " << theGift.m_wrapLayers << endl;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < theGift.m_wrapLayers; i++) {
            cout << "Wrap #" << i + 1 << " ->" << theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern << endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: Does `Gift` correctly implement copy constructor and copy assignment, as per the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can accurately answer the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: your problems comes from the line `theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = buffer;` in *wrap*, see my answer

Comment: @bruno, yes thank you it fixed it. The only thing left is I am allocating memory here             theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = new char[patternLength + 1]; how should i go about releasing it.

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs replacing `theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = buffer;` by `strcpy(theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern, buffer);` the rest of the code is a priori correct, including `delete[] theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern;`. Just the line `theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = nullptr;` is useless because after you do `delete[] theGift.m_wrap;`

Comment: @bruno ahh I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: As other hint, replace `void display(Gift& theGift){` by `void display(const Gift& theGift){` to clealy indicate you do not want to modify the argument, and to see the error the compiler produces in case you do. The more you restrict your code the better it is

Comment: Stepping on the LHS value of a new is called a memory leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error - *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff360: pointer being freed was not allocated.

in *wrap* :

> ```
> char buffer[100];
> ...
> theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = buffer;
> ```

you save in the in-out parameter *theGift* a pointer to the local array *buffer* (and you have a memory leak for the lost of the allocation done in `theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = new char[patternLength + 1];` just before)

and later in *unwrap* :

> ```
> delete[] theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern;
> ```

you try to delete that invalid pointer.

In fact in *wrap* rather than :

> ```
> theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = new char[patternLength + 1];
> theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = buffer;
> ```

you wanted to do :

```
 theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern = new char[patternLength + 1];
 strcpy(theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern, buffer);
```

---

Note you can also use `std::string` for *m_pattern* rather than array of char, and a `std::vector<Wrapping>`for *m_wrap* rather than an array of *Wrapping*. That simplify a lot, no `new` nor `delete`

Comment: Given the code, the poster might not be clear as to what the bug is here. They're probably assuming this copies the pointed data.  So: You're right, but can you explain it clearer?

Comment: @MooingDuck the error is `Error - *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff360: pointer being freed was not allocated.`, this is what the code I extracted does